# Delphi - Array[0..693] of Byte - to B64 Encoded String

Tags: delphi, arrays, base64, delphi-xe2

I have a declared variable in my code like so:

```
Var
   VarName:Array[0..693] of Byte = ( and my array here );
```

I have EncdDecd in my uses..

I am looking to encode this Array of Byte into a base64 string using the EncodeBase64 function in EncdDecd.pas

But I am unsure of how to return it into a nice and pretty b64 string that can be converted directly back into a byte array with DecodeBase64...

I have tried a few different approaches..

```
Var Res:PWideChar;
begin
    StringToWideChar(EncodeBase64(@VarName, 693), Res, 693);
    ClipBoard.SetTextBuf(Res);
end;
```

Access Violation with that code...

Also tried:

```
begin
    ClipBoard.SetTextBuf(PWideChar(EncodeBase64(@VarName, 693)));
end;
```

Which returns a string full of distorted Chinese symbols....

Any help on returning this string would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions are declared as

```
function  DecodeBase64(const Input: AnsiString): TBytes;
function  EncodeBase64(const Input: Pointer; Size: Integer): AnsiString;
```

so all you need in Unicode Delphi's is to cast AnsiString to string,

```
var S: string;

begin
  S:= string(EncodeBase64(@VarName, 693));
  ..
```

to decode S you should cast it to AnsiString:

```
var B: TBytes;

begin
  B:= DecodeBase64(AnsiString(S));
  ..
```

Comment: What unit are the functions `DecodeBase64` and `EncodeBase64` declared in?